# Linux Quota Custom Error Message via SFTP

Tags: linux, sftp, winscp, quota

Is it possible to pass a **custom error message to the sftp client** when the user exceeds the soft or at least the hard **quota limit**?

My SFTP Client (WinSCP) shows me an error message in which it states that the server should provide an error description - which it isn´t doing.

Link to WinSCP error message description: http://winscp.net/eng/docs/message_error_code_4

Searching online didn´t provide me the answer if it is possible at all - or how it could be accomplished.

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OpenSSH as the error suggests, there's no way to get customized quota messages.

Of course except for modifying the OpenSSH SFTP server source code and recompiling. It's open source after all :)